# PhantomJS 'click' event works on link, but not button?

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, nodes

I'm scraping dynamic content with PhantomJS. I want to load this website: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/fun/, and click the button at the bottom of the screen "load more" to load more pictures, and save the HAR content. This code works:

```
            var page require('webpage').create();

            page.open('http://www.milliondollarhomepage.com', function(status) {

            setTimeout(function(){
            page.sendEvent('click', 240, 210, button='left') }, 200);

            setTimeout(function(){
            page.render("screensho1.png");
                    phantom.exit();
                }, 5000);

            });
```

It clicks a --link-- on the screen. But when I use my URL of interest, https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/fun/ the same code with the proper coordinates won’t click the ---button---.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Positioning of elements is often relative, so I would recommend to avoid absolute click events; instead work with selectors and trigger a click event on the element:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');

var url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/fun/";

page.open(url, function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {

    setTimeout(
        function(){
            page.evaluate(
                function(){document.querySelector("#react-root > section > main > article > div > div > a").click();}
            );
        }, 200);

    setTimeout(
        function(){
            path = 'hardcoded.png';
            page.render(path, {format: 'png', quality: '100'});
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000);

    }else{
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```